# Implementing Swift UI Picker

Tags: swiftui

What is the correct way to implement a Picker component with specific logic within a Section element?

I would like to have each type displayed in a separate row.

```
var types = ["Books", "Films", "Music"]

var body: some View {
    Form {
        Section(header: Text("Type")) {
            TextField("Type", text: $newCategoryType)
            // Picker
        }          
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you must have a `@State` property that can be updated based on what selection the user makes, say in this case we have this

```
@State private var selectedType = "Books"
```

Then you will implement a `Picker` SwiftUI struct as follows

```
Picker("Please choose a type", selection: $selectedType) {
                ForEach(types, id: \.self) {
                    Text($0)
                }
            }
```

Note that the `\.self` is really important for `ForEach` to distinguish between each element inside the list, without which the `Picker` won't perform the selection action correctly.

The above is enough for doing the job of displaying each option as a row since that is the default behaviour of `ForEach`
Additionally if you want to customise the look and feel of the picker
you would like to see `.pickerStyle()` view modifier, for which the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/pickerstyle) and [examples](https://dev.to/tprezioso/picker-view-styles-in-swiftui-16oh) are mentioned

Also
**Tip**:  Because pickers in forms have this navigation behavior, it’s important you present them in a `NavigationView` on iOS otherwise you’ll find that tapping them doesn’t work. This might be one you create directly around the form, or you could present the form from another view that itself was wrapped in a `NavigationView`.

Comment: Thank you @gtxtreme for a very precise answer! It solved my problem beautifully!